How to pass connection string parameter type into Get Data PostgreSQL db connector in Power BI Desktop?
I have all my reports built in Power BI Desktop, using its native PostgreSQL DB connector to retrieve data. The source is a Neon Tech PostgreSQL instance. Now, during an update, I receive the error: "PostgreSQL XX000: Insecure connection: try using 'sslmode=require'."
This is not a problem, but the connector dialog window does not support parameters. I have all my data in that database, so I cannot apply common workarounds like using ODBC, changing server-side configuration, or switching to another service.
Thank you!
I've tried rolling back my Power BI Desktop update, as the problem began three versions ago. I also attempted to install the Npgsql driver version 4.0.16. Additionally, I tried passing parameters through the server, database name, and credentials fields in the advanced options.
I hope to find out if there are no other solutions than migrating to a different database service or technology.

I tried older versions from Oct, back 3 versions. None of them solved the problem.
I finally solved it by continuing to try different versions of the Npgsql driver. The one that works for me is Npgsql v4.0.12 (with pbi desktop v.OCT2024).

To resolve this issue, try downgrading to an earlier version of Power BI Desktop. I reverted to the August 2024 release, which resolved the problem. You can find previous versions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-latest-update-archive?tabs=powerbi-desktop

I've tried just that, from oct version, back 3 versions, no one solved the problem. I finally solved by keep tryng installing differents versions of Npgsql driver. The one thats works for me is the v4.0.12 - and the pbi desktop v.OCT2024
